# Having More than One Info Part in LinkedList

Tags: linked-list, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

We have been given an assignment of implementing priority queue using linked lists. The logic in my mind is that if I add 2 info parts to the node, one for containing the data to print & other for storing a key to prioritize the node, then I can dequeue the node according to the priority.

Now I am just confused as to whether it is legal to add two info parts to a single node?

Like

```
private class Node {

  private int priority;
  private String job;
  private Node Next;

}
```

If it is a doubly linked list then the reverse pointer is also necessary.

Comment: What you seem to be asking is whether you can add more than one field (other than pointers to other Nodes in the list) to a Node object - is that the case? If so, then yes you can, at least in Java, which is what this looks like. More to the point - have you tried adding the two fields and seeing if it works? If not, in what way doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly fine to put two pieces of information in a node in a linked list. In fact, if you're building a priority queue, you will probably *need* some kind of priority 'key' to order your queue, as well as a 'value', (a.k.a. 'data' or 'payload') that the node is holding onto for later use.

In your case, the String is the value and the int is the key / priority. You can think of this node as having one piece of information (the String), besides its key.

If that's not exactly what you're after, you could make a more flexible linked list that could hold any data in its node, including a single piece of data that contained both an int and a String. This could therefore be used for a priority queue or any other kind of abstract data structure built on a linked list.

Your code looks like Java, so if you'd like to know how to make this more flexible node in Java you can look into [Generics in Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java).

Comment: Thanks Matt Farrugia, I am Intentionally not Using Generics, However if i use Generics as Recommended By You, Still Only The Info Part Which i Use To keep Data Will Be Turned To A Generic DataType, The Key Part will  Still be Present In Order To Give Priority To The Nodes, Am i Right?

Comment: You can use Generics for the info part you use to keep data, or for both the info and the priority. Either option is fine if you are making a priority queue with your linked list.